# Unable to access web service url

Tags: web-services

I have created a web service whose url is accessible from local machine or from machines in the same domain. However when I access the url from machine in different domain, I get page can't be displayed message.
URL: http://1.2.3.4/FileTxfrWebService/FileTxfr.asmx

I'm able to ping the machine which is hosting the web service from different domain, but why it's not possible to fetch the URL?

Comment: because it's a different machine? could be ...

Comment: What do you have for security {require SSL., authenticate, login mechanism}?

Comment: Well there is no authentication (no login is required), it's not even https, it's just a simple http